# How to print only unique solutions to an optimization problem for which the solution depends on the initial guess?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem of 4 equations with 4 unknowns. Since the solution depends on the initial guess, I want to randomize the initial guess and check the solution. I want to let python repeat this thousands of times and then collect all the unique solutions. Any ideas how I can do this?

This is what I got, but I can't figure out how I can print unique solutions only. Currently with only 10 random initial guesses, but I'd like to do it with thousands.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import random
```

```py
def equations(x):
    p1 = x[0]
    p2 = x[1]
    t1 = x[2]
    t2 = x[3]
    f1 = -1725*p1*(t1 + 1) + 210*p2*(t2 + 1) + (p1 - 0.4)*(-1725*t1 - 1725) + 3804.25
    f2 = -80.8*p1*(t1 + 1) - 43.2*p2*(t2 + 1) + (p2 - 0.19)*(-43.2*t2 - 43.2) + 1221.55
    f3 = -1725*p1**2*t1 - 80.8*p1*p2*t2 + p1*(-1725*p1*(t1 + 1) + 210*p2*(t2 + 1) + 3804.25) + 3721.65*p1
    f4 = 210*p1*p2*t1 - 43.2*p2**2*t2 + p2*(-80.8*p1*(t1 + 1) - 43.2*p2*(t2 + 1) + 1221.55) + 302.7*p2
    return (f1,f2,f3,f4)
```

```py
mylist = []
times_to_repeat=10
while times_to_repeat >= 0:
    x=optimize.fsolve(equations,np.random.randint(-1000,1000,size=4)) 
    times_to_repeat -= 1
    mylist.append(x)  
print(type(x))
print(type(mylist))
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```py
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'list'>
[array([  0.6766083 , -16.36251351,   2.80326423,  -1.71285248]), array([   0.70453984,    0.20006569,    3.71919204,  103.97195662]), array([  0.6766083 , -16.36251351,   2.80326423,  -1.71285248]), array([  5.71533971e-11,  -2.78802240e-10,  -6.51340581e+00,
        -1.49824317e+02]), array([  1.15380439e-14,   4.54997307e-01,  -1.19518826e+01,
         3.82733776e+01]), array([   0.70453984,    0.20006569,    3.71919204,  103.9719566 ]), array([   0.70453984,    0.20006569,    3.71919204,  103.9719566 ]), array([   0.70453984,    0.20006569,    3.71919204,  103.9719566 ]), array([ -1.15803237, -20.50033894,  -2.37625565,  -1.61411274]), array([  3.74219997e-01,  -2.19855824e-11,   5.32924565e+00,
        -1.26508376e+02]), array([ -2.33169826e+00,  -3.58746853e-10,  -1.43554999e+00,
        -1.39826980e+02])]
```

Comment: Since you are using `scipy` (that's an educated guess!), the result is a `numpy` array.  You could also use `np.random.randint` to generate the initial guess.  You can collect the results in a list.  I'd use `np.isclose` to compare results, since floats rarely match exactly.

Comment: You could also use `scipy.spatial.KDTree` to identify close solutions in better than `O(N^2)` time.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your help. I got a list of arrays now. I'm not sure how to use the np.isclose function you suggested to find the unique arrays though. Could you help me out? I edited the original post to add the rest of the code as I realized this may be useful.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Thanks for your help. I'm a bit confused how to use scipy.spatial.KDTree. Could you explain how I use it to find unique arrays in a list of arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I am essentially answering the question of identifying close solutions among the list of solutions. One approach would be to use k-means clustering (in scipy, this requires guessing the number of solutions). Another would be to use initialize a KDTree of solutions, compute close pairs and return centroids of the connected components in the induced graph.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
import networkx as nx

# if you can guess the number of different solutions
def close_solutions_kmeans(points, guess_n_sols=n_centroids):
    return kmeans(points, guess_n_sols)[0]


# direct method with KDTree
def close_solutions_kdtree(points, close):
    visited = np.zeros(points.shape[0], bool)
    representative_solutions = list()
    # make a KDTree for fast neighbor lookup
    tree = cKDTree(points)
    # make a graph to search for connected components
    g = nx.Graph()
    g.add_nodes_from(np.arange(points.shape[0]))
    g.add_edges_from(tree.query_pairs(close))
    # return mean of points in each connected component
    return np.array([points[list(c)].mean(0)
        for c in nx.connected_components(g)])
```

In 2D, the result may look somewhat like this:

[image]

Pale blue points are the solutions, red points are kmeans centroids and blue points are kdtree solutions (blue and red points may overlap).

It is worth noting that there is some freedom in how you identify close solutions. For example, it may be that `a` is close to `b`, `b` is close to `c` but `a` is not close to `c`, possibly leading to ambiguity. In the `close_solutions_kdtree` function, we first construct a graph whose vertices are individual solutions and connect pairs of close solutions with an edge. Centroids of connected components are the representative solutions.

If you look at the plot above, there is only one blue dot in the central region, representing three visibly distinct groups of solutions, and illustrating the previous point.